Copy cell value and paste it to another cell if a check box is selected, and if not, put a specific value
I have data in sheet1 with check boxes in column A. I have a search field in cell B2. This cell B2 is referenced to a filter function. The filter function is located in cell B4. So when I search for a specific word, it will populate or return values to cells B5, C5 and D5.
So I what I am looking at is to copy the cell value on C5 only as a static data to cell G5 when checkbox A5 is checked/true, if not checked then put a word "Exempt". My goal here is I want to use the value copied in cell G5 as a static reference in a different formula even when the value on C5 changes after the script is run.
This is my current formula and it is actually working with the onEdit trigger, but my problem is that when the check boxes are checked rapidly or unchecked, the value is not changing and it would take a long time, like more than 30 seconds to update. Sometimes it won't make any changes at all
function selecteditem (e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var editedCell = e.range;

    if (pasteSheet.getName() == "Sheet1") {
      if (editedCell.getA1Notation() == "A5") {
        if (editedCell.isChecked()) {
          var valueToCopy = pasteSheet.getRange("C5").getValue();
          pasteSheet.getRange("G5").setValue(valueToCopy);
        } else {
          pasteSheet.getRange("G5").setValue("Exempt");
        }
      }
  }



The statement when the check boxes are checked rapidly or unchecked, the value is not changing and it would take a long time, like more than 30 seconds to update. is expected to happen because that's a limitation of onEdit(e), and the documentation states that Note: The onEdit() trigger only queues up to 2 trigger events.

That being said, it seems that Google's already aware of this matter, so a +1 to it would tell them that you're impacted by the issue. This is the link for the feature request: Only two onEdit trigger events can be queued at a time in New Sheets

I see, thank you for this answer. I read that thread and yes it will be very useful to increase trigger queues as it will be useful in case if there are corrections being made real time in the sheet. Usually users will edit multiple times on our sheet that is why I am asking for this.

Try this:
function selecteditem(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 5) {
    if (e.value == "TRUE")
      sh.getRange("G5").setValue(sh.getRange("C5").getValue(););
  } else {
    sh.getRange("G5").setValue("Exempt");
  }
}


This is what I was looking for, thank you!
